# Make a div inside a container to resize automatically

Tags: html, angular

I have a container, inside I have 3 . The first 2 don't have large content. I show and hide the first one with button click (I am using Angular). The 2nd one has a static content. I don't want to have a scroll for a container. I need only the 3rd div to scroll, it has a large content. When I make my container `overflow: hidden;` after showing my first div with button click, part of my 3rd div does not show. The 3rd  has this height `height: 100vh;`. I am new to CSS and HTML, how can I solve this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngIf="showContent" class="1st-content"></div>
  <div class="2nd-content"></div>
  <div class="3rd-content"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS.

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.3rd-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: "I think I miss something" – Indeed, you did miss posting an actual minimal example, including code, to demonstrate your situation.

Comment: Sorry, I have included the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for solution.

```
body, html {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }

.container {
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100%;
        }

.third-content {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
          overflow-y: scroll;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```